# How to drop rows that have subrows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning, data-preprocessing

I have  a dataframe like the table below with String columns and the Criteria column is float:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Crireria |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | b1 | c2 |  |  | 3 |
| a1 | b1 | c3 | d4 |  | 5 |
| a1 | b1 |  |  |  | 7 |
| a1 | b1 | c2 |  | e2 | 2 |
| a1 |  | c1 |  |  | 1 |

I want to drop a row if there is only one row that can be included to it and that have a greater or equal Criteria than it. i.e. I want to delete every row for which there is a row that has the same or higher criteria, but a more general row (its inputs are an appropriate subset of the deleted row's inputs).

my algorithm  is:

[image]

For example:

[image]

and so on

the desired output is:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Crireria |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | b1 |  |  |  | 7 |
| a1 |  | c1 |  |  | 1 |

Comment: What if you had a row with `{'a1', 'b1', 'c2'}` but in a different order? Would it count as a match?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: each row is considered as a group, so the order doesn't change the result.